# How can I make my CustomView returns View plus some more extra data in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want build a **CustomView** that it works almost the same as like **GeometryReader** in **functionality**, I do not want re build the existed GeometryReader, I want use it to show case of my goal, for example I created this **CustomView** which reads the Size of **content**, I want my CustomView could be able send back that read Value of size in form of closure as we seen often in Swift or SwiftUI,

**My Goal:** I am trying to receive Size of View, which has been read in **CustomView** and saved in **sizeOfText** in my **parent/ContentView** View as form of closure.

*Ps: I am not interested to Binding or using ObservableObject for this issue, the question try find the answer in way of sending back data as Closure form.*

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        CustomView { size in                    // <<: Here
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .background(Color.yellow)
            .onAppear() {
                print("read size is:", size.debugDescription)
            }
            .onChange(of: size) { newValue in
                print("read size is:", newValue.debugDescription)
            }
  
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State private var sizeOfText: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return content()
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.onAppear() { sizeOfText = geometry.size }
                    
                })
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Next is you ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66288673/14733292

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI measuring the height of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288575/swiftui-measuring-the-height-of-a-view)

Comment: @RajaKishan: in that Link you are reading available Space with Geometry reader, in my question I am reading the taking space/size with Text! So there is a Night and Day deference!

Comment: Your main point is, How to return size from custom view to your view?. so for your point is covered in this ans.

Comment: In that way of thinking yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifiy the type of content as `CGSize` and then pass `sizeOfText` to content.

If you wish to learn more about closure, visit swift Doc.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

```
import SwiftUI
struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State private var sizeOfText: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var content: (CGSize) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        return content(sizeOfText)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.onAppear() { sizeOfText = geometry.size } 
                })
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomView { size in
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .onAppear() {
                    print("read size is:", size.debugDescription)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type in the content closure like this: `var content: (_ size: CGFloat) -> Content`

And then you can call the closure with your desired value. The value can also be @State in CustomView.

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomView { size in // <-- Here
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .onAppear() {
                    // print("read size is:", size.debugDescription)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    @State private var sizeOfText: CGSize = CGSize()
    var content: (_ size: CGFloat) -> Content // <-- Here
    
    var body: some View {
        return content(10)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.onAppear() { sizeOfText = geometry.size }
                    
                })
    }
}
```